# Render React component into div in existing non-spa site on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a site that is not a spa. At one point when a button is click a div is created in the dom. After the div is created I want to render a React component into this div. My component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        date: null
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            //Here will be more controls
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

I'm running webpack on this file and in my original page I'm referencing the generated js file.

What code should I add to my button click code that is adding the div so I can render the component?

ps. Actually the functionality is a bit more complex, because we are scraping a page the user specifies and showing the html in an iframe through the srcdoc attribute. The scraped html has the div added and then we render a widget in the div so the user can preview what our widget would look like on their page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ReactDOM to render the component. Install and import react-dom in your project so that webpack bundles it for you. You might need to expose ReactDOM as global in your web pack configuration.
Below is a simple code snippet:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent/> ,
    document.getElementById(id) // id of element in your case div created
  );
```

Reference
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html

Comment: How do I make reactdom global? The rest of the site is already existing, not using react, and the JavaScript for that is not webpacked. And I probably cannot put reactdom.render in the same file as the react component since the doc it should render on is not available at load time